# tkinter getting variables from sub functions in other files to my gui?

Tags: python, tkinter, global-variables, nameerror

I have made a small programme that processes and copies files for myself as practice. I have an issue regarding my tkinter GUI.

My programme consists of ~30 different functions in 8 different files. I have 3 types: GUI, controllers and functionality. Added to this, I have a file to define global variables.

A simplified example:

My function for declaring global variables:

```
## Global variables
def do_some():
    global counter
    counter=0
```

My model, here just a loop and something that gets returned. Note the counter, which should be a global variable.

```
#model    
def loop_model():
   import time
   import global_vars

   counter = 0

   for count in range(100):
       time.sleep(1)
    
       counter +=1
    
       messageToGive = f"I have run {counter} times"
    
    return messageToGive
```

For my controller, I have this very short code, just for calling the model

```
# controller
def loop_controller():
    import model
    import global_vars

    model.loop_model()
```

My GUI is as below. This small script works, except for the Label.config. I get ´NameError: name 'counter' is not defined´, as in, it doesn't recognise my global variable. What am I doing wrong here? I recognise I could change my structure to return my counter in this example, but not easily so in my real script.

```
# GUI
import tkinter as tk
import global_vars

global_vars.do_some()

root = tk.Tk()

root.geometry("800x600") # Size of the window
root.title("The no-duplicate Media Importer") # Main window title

def run_looper():
    import controller
    controller.loop_controller()

runButton = tk.Button(text="run this loop", height = 8, width = 40, command=run_looper)
runButton.pack()

counterLb = tk.Label(text="0 loops done")
counterLb.pack()

counterLb.config(text=f"{counter} loops done") ###causes NameError

root.mainloop()
```

I hope You can help,

GregersDK

Answer (score 0):

When you write

```
import global_vars
```

Or

```
from global_vars import *
```

It only copies the name defined in global_vars into the current module if you wanna get access and control global_vars then qualified way to do is

```
global_vars.counter += 1
```

Or

```
counterLb.config(text=f"{global_vars.counter} loops done") ### Should not give any error and work fine.
```

Comment: I did this, and it surely did remove the errors. However, the larger question still remains: How do I get the label to update? The only thing I can think of is placing the .config in my model loop, but for many reasons, that is not really feasible in a real program. What else can be done to update the label?

Comment: @GregersDK you should place your `.config` inside `run_looper()` function.

Comment: Then the label updates after the full run of the loop, but how do I make it update the counter constantly, so I can see where in the loop I am?